# Connecting to ElastiCache (Outside VPC) instance from a EC2 inside VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache

We have large number of applications that uses one ElasticCache instance (Redis) which is located outside the VPC (a classic instance). Some Applications are located with in VPCs and Some are outside VPC (Classic instances). How can we connect all applications to the cache ?

We have no issue connecting applications outside VPC to the cache as the cache is also located outside VPC
There is a smaller number of applications inside VPCs that cannot connect to the cache.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its is not possible to directly access the classic-cluster from a VPC instance. The workaround would be configuring NAT on the classic instance.

NAT need to have a simple tcp proxy

```
YourIP=1.2.3.4
YourPort=80
TargetIP=2.3.4.5
TargetPort=22

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst $YourIP -p tcp --dport $YourPort -j DNAT \
--to-destination $TargetIP:$TargetPort
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dst $TargetIP --dport $TargetPort -j SNAT \
--to-source $YourIP
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT --dst $YourIP -p tcp --dport $YourPort -j DNAT \
--to-destination $TargetIP:$TargetPort
```

More details: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Access.Outside.html

Comment: were you able to solve this? I am running into the same problem now. We have a number of services that we are trying to migrate inside of an VPC, but they rely on classic redis instances outside of the VPC. I don't seem to figure out how to connect the two.