# could not connect aws elasticache redis from .net app

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, redis, amazon-elasticache

I am connecting .NET core app to AWS ElastiCache Redis. 
[image]

The AWS Elasticache Redis is running and port 6329 is open on security group. The client code is using `StackExchange.Redis`:

```
           var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("redis-1.xxxx.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379");
           //var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost"); //working
           IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();

            string value = "abcdefg";
            db.StringSet("mykey", value);        

            string value2 = db.StringGet("mykey");
            Console.WriteLine(value2); // writes: "abcdefg"

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Exception is:

> It was not possible to connect to the redis server(s). UnableToConnect
>   on redis-1.xxx.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/Interactive,
>   Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync,
>   outstanding: 0, last-read: 5s ago, last-write: 5s ago, keep-alive:
>   60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat:
>   never, global: 0s ago, v: 2.0.601.3402

Added to `,abortConnect=false` to the endpoint, I am able to connect.

Now the error is at `StringSet`

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException: 'No connection is
>   available to service this operation: SET mykey; UnableToConnect ...

**The .NET code is working fine with my local Redis service so looks like something incorrect with my AWS setup.**

Successfully `ssh` to my EC2-instance and redis-cli to my AWS redis service:
[image]

Any idea please?

**NOTE:** AWS Elasticache Redis is NOT available for public access as default.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/accessing-elasticache.html#access-from-outside-aws
- [Can you connect to Amazon ElastiСache Redis outside of Amazon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917661/can-you-connect-to-amazon-elasti%D0%A1ache-redis-outside-of-amazon)

Comment: Maybe try connecting to the server using redis-cli from your workstation?

Comment: successfully ssh into a ec2-instance and run redis-cli againt my aws redis service. But still failed from .net app (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/GettingStarted.ConnectToCacheNode.html)

Comment: Just to be clear, you're getting this error when you deploy your code to the same EC2 instance? In that case, there shouldn't be any issues since the redis-cli can connect fine.

Comment: I am running .net code from my machine. Thought `redis-1.xxxx.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379` is public available via security group (TCP\6379 for All IPs)?

Comment: Try to connect to your redis server from your own machine then with redis-cli, not from the EC2.

Comment: Also, if your redis cluster does not have a public IP address, you cannot connect to it remotely even if you have the proper rules enabled. So check for that maybe. It's difficult to tell without knowing the actual hostname.

Comment: Failed to run redis-cli to redis-1.xxxx.0001.use1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379 from my machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209622/discussion-between-trinopoty-and-beewest).

Answer (score 0):

Question: "...port 6329 is open on security group.." Dont you mean 6379?

Even that, i think i cn have an issue on the "default" subnet groups.

Does the VPC_Subnet (in that group) where the AWS ElastiCache Redis is, has a Routing Table with access to the Internet Gateway?
If not, you need to attache the InternetGteway to the Route Table and than use that Route Table on the Subnet that you want.

It should be like the pick:
[Internet GW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrcAL.png)