# How to connect my developer machine with Amazon Memory DB Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpn, amazon-memory-db

Memory DB Cluster configured, connected with an EC2 instance within same VPC. but cannot telnet Memory DB Cluster even when connected via vpn where as from EC2 instance, telnet and redis-cli both works.

Configured VPN via OpenVPN and connected. I can access EC2 instance [telnet etc] via private IP when connected with VPN, but could not connect with Memory DB cluster. need to connect my developer machine to be connected with DB Cluster to proceed.

tried to find any private IP of cluster or something by which i can connect but couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of VPN it would be easy to do ssh tunnelling to do port forwarding for development purposes . Create a bastion host and ssh tunnel and forward the Memory db port. you can follow the instructions which were done for RDS port forward https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connect-using-bastion-host-linux/

Comment: thats exactly what i [Port forwarding], got help from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21917661/can-you-connect-to-amazon-elasti%d0%a1ache-redis-outside-of-amazon)