# unable to connect to aws elastic cache from windows machine?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elasticache

Can anyone please guide me on how to connect to aws elastic cache from the windows machine?

I have installed redis-cli in my windows and trying to connect to the host but it is getting stuck and unable to connect.

Comment: You might be looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21917661/12326605

Comment: What have you tried? What happens? What is your architecture (eg where is your Windows computer)? What is the configuration of the Security Group on the Elasticache instance?